# LoginActivity has leaked window DecorView@bb62df1[LoginActivity] that was originally added here

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I keep getting the error that my Login Activity has a leaked window of some sort,
This is my block of code where the error occurs. I have tried to dismiss both the dialog and the Alert Box respectively, but still, keep getting this error.

```
    try
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
        builder.setTitle(R.string.login_ok_title);
        builder.setMessage(R.string.login_ok_text).setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, (dialog, id) ->
        {
            Intent intent =new Intent(LoginActivity.this, TrackActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            TrackManagerService trackManager =TrackManagerService.getInstance();
            if (trackManager != null) {
                trackManager.setLoginListener(null);
            }

            LoginActivity.this.finish();
            dialog.dismiss();
        });
        alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();

    } 
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, TrackActivity.class);
        alert.dismiss();
        startActivity(intent);
        TrackManagerService trackManager = TrackManagerService.getInstance();
        if (trackManager != null) 
        {
            trackManager.setLoginListener(null);
        }
        finish();
    }
```

This is the Error Log

```
E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.example.tornado_app.LoginActivity has leaked window DecorView@59e20b9[LoginActivity] that was originally added here
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:627)
    at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:389)
    at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:131)
    at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:531)
    at com.example.tornado_app.LoginActivity$2.lambda$onLoginResult$4$LoginActivity$2(LoginActivity.java:160)
    at com.example.tornado_app.-$$Lambda$LoginActivity$2$YvCiBtxWavxZ1iGtdLspSkuZOdU.run(Unknown Source:6)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:907)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7625)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
```

Comment: don't dismiss dialog after starting another activity. Dismiss it before staring another activity.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Activity has leaked window that was originally added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850573/activity-has-leaked-window-that-was-originally-added)

Comment: I did check it, that is when i added the alert.dismiss(); statement but it kept occurring.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

pls try to check if activity is finished or not before showing dialog.

```
 if (!isFinishing()){
       alert.show();
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I did do that before but it still kept giving me this issue.

Comment: I changed my answer. pls try it once

Comment: I just did but it still throws this error    

`Activity com.example.tornado_app.LoginActivity has leaked window DecorView@aeec1d9[LoginActivity] that was originally added here
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:627) at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:389) at com.example.tornado_app.LoginActivity$2.lambda$onLoginResult$4$LoginActivity$2(LoginActivity.java:160)`

Comment: thank you this worked well , I tried to rebuild and clean the project and then ran it again.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you use 2 time `dialog.dismiss();` and after activity finish how you can dismiss dialog?Try to add below code

```
try {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(LoginActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.login_ok_title);
    builder.setMessage(R.string.login_ok_text).setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, (dialog, id) ->
    {
        //dialog.dismiss(); //Remove this
        Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, TrackActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        TrackManagerService trackManager = TrackManagerService.getInstance();
        if (trackManager != null) {
            trackManager.setLoginListener(null);
        }

        LoginActivity.this.finish();
        //dialog.dismiss(); //Remove this
    });
    alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();

} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, TrackActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    TrackManagerService trackManager = TrackManagerService.getInstance();
    if (trackManager != null) {
        trackManager.setLoginListener(null);
    }
    finish();
}
```

I hope this can help you!

Comment: Are you try this?

Comment: Yes I did,and it did not work. i want it to dismiss after the activity starts, i.e why i kept below the startActivity().

Comment: @Ibrahim117 are you try to remove dialog.dismiss() to all code?

Comment: May be error is something else can you share your full LoginActivity code?

Comment: Here You Go,
https://gist.github.com/ibrahim-iqbal/6e7c6de6417aae0c547b11b85b9b872e

Comment: you are already start activity at line number 175 & 176 comment your code at line 175 to 182

Comment: Thank You, it really helped me and made me clean up my code more precisely.

Comment: @Ibrahim117 Is it helpful for you?